# Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction for BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE

Tags: spring-batch

In Spring batch v4.2.1 we are getting error - SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction.

Tried all the workaround mentioned at the bottom of this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1127) but it did not resolve. In lower environments ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED fixed the issue but in Prod the error still occurs. Please help how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have the same oracle version in all environments?

Comment: Yes the ORACLE version is the same

Comment: If it works in one environment but not the other with the same oracle version, then you need to check if there are other differences that might affect the result. Without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, it is hard to find the root cause.

Comment: I checked CP settings and other details but everything is same. Meanwhile came across this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#CNCPT1321 and suggests if the error occurs, rollback the trx and restart again. Is this something that Spring batch v4.2.1 can provide a fix?

Comment: @PrashantS there is a Spring Batch issue open: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1127

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue got fixed by implementing BatchConfigurer interface and override getJobRepository() to set explicit isolation level.

We also tried other fixes (change initrans, extend DefaultBatchConfigurer, defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED" in DS context.xml) but none of them worked unfortunately.

Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine for your inputs

```
@Override
@Bean
public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(getPrimaryDataSource());
    factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());

    //Explicit set isolation level in order to avoid ORA-08177 error that occurred when multiple jobs run at the same time default is Serializable
    factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
    return factory.getObject();
}
```